# How do I move the sidebar on the right? Push it more right side?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I can only add Custom CSS to it. I want to push it a bit more on the right side so that my text (article) width can increase.

Here is my website, http://www.defensionem.com/schwellenpflug/

http://www.defensionem.com.

Notice the side-bar on the right, which has a link for Facebook. I want my content to appear in the "middle" of the screen hence I added a bit of padding on the left. But I find I am unable to increase the width of the text.

How do I move the side-bar a bit to the right?

Yes I did try, but nothing worked.

Also, how do I hide the the paragraph tags?

http://www.defensionem.com/profile/Renaud-Mayers/

I typed that info in the Wordpress column. (I cannot make a new post for 90mins so I added it here. Sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to do lower the margin-right value:

```
.content-wrapper__inside.sidebar--true.sidebar--right .main-content__inside
{
    margin-right: 180px;
}
```

Be aware that the styles are for a responsive site. So you might have to change it for other screen sizes as well.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you put your paragraph tags inside of the quotes:

```
"<p>Currently working on behalf of the Belgian Ministry of Defence, thanks to my high knowledge in WWII and other areas. Working in two WWII era fortresses still belonging to the Army.</p>"
```

just move them to the outside, or perhaps get rid of them altogether.